# how to remove specific xml elements from the xml content using C#4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

This is xml content.

```
<w:tbl xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:tr>
      <w:tc>
         <w:p>
           <w:r><w:t>1</w:t></w:r>
         </w:p>
         <w:p /> <!-- needs to remove -->
         <w:p /> <!-- needs to remove -->
       </w:tc>
       <w:tc>
         <w:p>
           <w:r><w:t>2</w:t></w:r>
         </w:p>
         <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
         <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
       </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr>
      <w:tc>
         <w:p>
           <w:r><w:t>3</w:t></w:r>
         </w:p>
         <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
         <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
       </w:tc>
       <w:tc>
         <w:p>
           <w:r><w:t>4</w:t></w:r>
         </w:p>
         <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
         <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
       </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

Actually this xml content are generated by html to ooxml converter[HtmlToOpenXml.dll].But it wrongly added the two `<w:p>` elements at end of the every `<w:tc>` elements.So, i want to remove those `<w:p>` elements from the xml content generated by the converter.I have the xml content in string format.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you just use a string replace?

```
xmlString.Replace("<w:p />", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If everything is that easy, I strongly suggest using the answer by @sylon. 
Anyway, this is a simple example of how to do this with LINQ to XML:

```
        XElement x = XElement.Load("In.xml");
        string prefix = "w";
        XNamespace w = x.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(prefix);
        var ds = x.Descendants(w + "p")
                  .Where(d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.Value));
        ds.Remove();
        x.Save("Out.xml");
```

The `Where` clause can contain more specific conditions, if you needed to remove some more specific tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
string xmlString = @"<w:tbl xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'>
      <w:tr>
          <w:tc>
             <w:p>
               <w:r><w:t>1</w:t></w:r>
             </w:p>
             <w:p /> <!-- needs to remove -->
             <w:p /> <!-- needs to remove -->
           </w:tc>
           <w:tc>
             <w:p>
               <w:r><w:t>2</w:t></w:r>
             </w:p>
             <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
             <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
           </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
      <w:tr>
          <w:tc>
             <w:p>
               <w:r><w:t>3</w:t></w:r>
             </w:p>
             <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
             <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
           </w:tc>
           <w:tc>
             <w:p>
               <w:r><w:t>4</w:t></w:r>
             </w:p>
             <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
             <w:p />  <!-- needs to remove -->
           </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
doc.Root.Descendants().Where(d => d.IsEmpty && !d.HasAttributes).Remove();
```

Comment: But it is much slower than just replace `<w:p />` with `string.Empty`.